# How to encrypt text by 3DES, CBC mode using Javascript on APIGEE

Tags: javascript, encryption, apigee, 3des, cbc-mode

Here is my information:

- Plain Text: ---------------------------------------------------

  - do not encode
- Key: ------------------------------------

  - do not encode
- Ecryption Algorithm: 3DES, CBC mode with symmetric key
- Init Vector : ------------------------------

  - I knew only "iv must be hexa form"

**Desired Output:**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm using this library: https://cdn.rawgit.com/CryptoStore/crypto-js/3.1.2/build/rollups/tripledes.js

**My function to encrypt:**

```
function encryptByDES(message, key){
  var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(8);
  var encrypted = CryptoJS.TripleDES.encrypt(message, key, {
    iv: key,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
  });
  return encrypted.toString();
}
```

**Actual Output:**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Question:** How do I achieve my desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of oddities and issues with your inputs/outputs and code:

- You have a Base64 plaintext which you pass as plain UTF8 (???), UTF8 encoded key and hex encoded IV.  Ideally you should operate under one encoding for all three values.  I recommend base64 if you can't operate using plain binary.
- You're using a fixed IV, which introduces a number of vulnerabilities that can result in plaintext recovery.  Always randomly generate an IV for each encryption operation.
- You're passing the key as the IV during encryption, so the IV that you do generate is not used anyway.  **Never use the key as an IV**.

I have solved your issue and have produced the desired output but I am not going to post the code, as you won't learn anything.  Instead I'll tell you what you need to do to fix what you have:

- Modify your existing to code to actually use the IV.
- Pass the plaintext and key as binary data to the encrypt function by using `CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse` to get each as binary words.
- Output the result as hex and not as base64.

EDIT: The code used to produce the desired result.  Note the conversion from base64 to hex for the `output` variable:

```
let iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("0000000000000000");
let pt = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("MjAxODAxMDQwOTM5MzgxMjM0NTY3ODkwMTIzNA==");
let key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("20180104093938xSpUoDU3Z0");

let result = CryptoJS.TripleDES.encrypt(pt, key, {
    iv: iv,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
});

let output = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(result.toString()));
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But i don't understand this "Modify your existing to code to actually use the IV." this means i have to use iv = '0000000000000000' right?

Comment: Look in the code you posted.  You've got `iv: key`.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I really don't understand. `function encryptByDES(message, key){
 var binaryMessage = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(message);
 var binaryKey = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);
 var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(8);
 var encrypted = CryptoJS.TripleDES.encrypt(binaryMessage, binaryKey, {
  iv: iv,
  mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
 });

 return encrypted.toString();
}` I have modified to this. but I can't get my desired output. What I missed something you told me?

Comment: Very close, well done.  You are actually getting the correct output, it is just encoded as base64 instead of hex as you want.  I've edited my answer to include the code I used to get your result.

Comment: Thank you so much. I never do anything about 3DES. This is my first lesson.

Comment: No worries.  I highly recommend you don't use this code in production, however.  It isn't remotely secure.